# What's wrong with my __rmul__? (numpy.poly1d * custom object)

Tags: python, numpy, methods

I made a *piecewise polynomial* object based on `numpy.poly1d`.  It has all the usual arithmetic methods plus `deriv()` and `integ()`.  Create it with a list of breakpoints and a list of `poly1d`s.

I am stumped by this behavior:

```
>>> from numpy import poly1d
>>> from piecepoly import PiecePoly as pp
>>> f = poly1d([-1,-1])
>>> g = pp([-1,1], [poly1d([-1]),poly1d([1,0]),poly1d([1])])
>>> g(-2)
-1
>>> g(-0.7)
-0.69999999999999996
>>> g(0.3)
0.29999999999999999
>>> g(4)
1
>>> h = g*f
>>> h1 = h.integ()
>>> j = f*g
>>> j1 = j.integ()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/polynomial.py", line 1216, in integ
    return poly1d(polyint(self.coeffs, m=m, k=k))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/polynomial.py", line 320, in polyint
    y = NX.concatenate((p.__truediv__(NX.arange(len(p), 0, -1)), [k[0]]))
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'instance' and 'int'
```

The flaw would seem to be in `__rmul__`, but that is simply `return self.__mul__(other)`.

As requested in comment, here is `integ` (which another project tested to my satisfaction):

```
    def integ(self, n=1):
        if n == 0: return self
        if n < 0: return self.deriv(-n)
        if self.integral == None:
            intemp = [ f.integ() for f in self.func ]
            fl = intemp.pop(0)
            outf = [fl]
            for t, fr in zip(self.breaks, intemp):
                fr += fl(t) - fr(t)
                outf.append(fr)
                fl = fr
            self.integral = PiecePoly(self.breaks, outf)
            self.integral.derivative = self
        if n==1: return self.integral
        return self.integral.integ(n-1)
```

Comment: Have you checked that the values of h and j at a few points are consistent? Have you also checked that the polynomial pieces match? It would also probably help for us to be able to see your integration routine.

Comment: One of the multiplicands here is a simple poly1d, no breaks, so there's no issue of matching the pieces.

Comment: I have a guess what is going wrong based on the error message. Python tries to call __mul__ on the left operand before calling __rmul__ on the right. I think the poly1D __mul__ is succeeding, leading j to be a (incorrectly initialized) poly1D. Then when you call integ, it's using the poly1D integ and producing an the listed error due to the incorrect initialization. I would suggest trying to run your program with a debugger to see the path it's taking to get to this error message.

Comment: Shouldn't `poly1d.__mul__` simply give up because it does not recognize the other operand?

Comment: I think poly1D is actually set up to work with object arrays and multiplication by arbitrary objects. I would have to look at the source code more https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.19.0/numpy/lib/polynomial.py#L256-L348

Comment: On further experimentation, it appears that `j` is a `poly1d` whose coefficients are `PiecePoly`s!  Ugh.  I'll probably have to replace every `poly1d`, wherever it's at risk of being multiplied to a `PiecePoly`, with a `PiecePoly` whose breaklist is empty.

Comment: It's puzzling, though, that in `poly1d.integ` the division of a`PiecePoly` by an integer fails. (Doing so would give a wrong answer here, but still.)